# Javascript: callback context between class borders

Tags: javascript, oop, asynchronous, request

I have a problem with the contexts of callbacks and javascript classes.
Basically, I know that inside a callback function body, the this-argument is undefined and therefore we need some tricks like the introduction of a additional self-argument.

However, in my code I have two layers of indirection and I really cannot get things figured out.

OK, here's my task:
I'm writing a class for doing some fancy stuff on some data.
The data comes from http-requests, and I want the network logic and json parsing to be encapsulated in a different class (a generic communication class which can be used elsewhere).

This means:

- myFancyClass creates an instance of myCommunicationClass
- myFancyClass triggers network request via myCommunicationClass
- because the network request is async, myCommunicationClass has to inform myFancyClass when the data is ready via callback
  And this is where I'm lost.

example code:

```
class myFancyClass {

        indicationCallback(data) {
            /* store the data*/
            this.data=data; // This is not working!!
        }

    doSomeStuff() {
        this.conn = new myCommunicationClass(ip, port, indicationCallback);
        this.conn.ExecuteRequest();
    }
}


class myCommunicationClass{
    constructor(ip, port, callback) {
        /* remember callback for later use */
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    ExecuteRequest() {
        /* set up request options */
        var self = this;
        request.post(options, function(error, response, body) {
                /* check for errors, otherwise call callback*/
                self.callback(receivedData)
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm already familiar with the "self = this-trick".
However, when myCommunicationClass calls the callback, the context of the myFancyClass  object is no longer valid.

To some it up: I have callbacks and I have two classes involved, which makes it even harder (for me) to get the right contexts figured out.
Whats your approach on this?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use `this` when referencing the `indicationCallback` method. In the example below I've assumed that `ip` and `port` are also properties on the `myFancyClass` object.

```
class myFancyClass {

    indicationCallback(data) {
        /* store the data*/
        this.data=data; // This is not working!!
    }

    doSomeStuff() {
        this.conn = new myCommunicationClass(this.ip, this.port, this.indicationCallback);
        this.conn.ExecuteRequest();
    }
}
```

Comment: you're right, the this. was missing in all three cases.
But this was not the solution.
I found out that you need to bind() the callback:
this.conn = new myCommunicationClass(this.ip, this.port, this.indicationCallback.bind(this));
Now it's working for me